# Determine whether a string only contains certain characters in R

Tags: r, grepl

How do I determine whether a string contains only space or 0 in R?

String: “01234”
Output: False

String: “0 0 0”
Output: True

String: “000”
Output: True

String: “ “
Output: True

Answer (score 4):

Test for not `0` or   with `[^0 ]` and negate the result with `!`.

```
x <- c("01234", "0 0 0", "000", " ")

!grepl("[^0 ]", x)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```